# I created a simple CRUD Application using ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

here is my UPDATE page code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication2.Pages.Users
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        public UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";
        public void OnGet()
        {
            String id=Request.Query["id"];

            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-5406L1M;Initial Catalog=crud;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=@id";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                userInfo.id = ""+reader.GetInt32(0);
                                userInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                                userInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                                userInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                                userInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            userInfo.id = Request.Form["id"];
            userInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
            userInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            userInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            userInfo.address = Request.Form["address"];

            if (userInfo.id.Length==0 ||userInfo.name.Length == 0 || userInfo.email.Length == 0 || userInfo.phone.Length == 0 || userInfo.address.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the field are required";
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-5406L1M;Initial Catalog=crud;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql ="UPDATE users " +
                               "SET name=@name, email=@email, phone=@phone, address=@address " +
                               "WHERE id=@id";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                       
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", userInfo.name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", userInfo.email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", userInfo.phone);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", userInfo.address);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userInfo.id);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage=ex.Message;
                return;
            }
            Response.Redirect("/Users/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

`

### Here is my Index page (userInfo class)

> Index page (userInfo class)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication2.Pages.Users
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<UserInfo> ListUsers=new List<UserInfo>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-5406L1M;Initial Catalog=crud;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                    using (SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                                userInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                userInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                                userInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                                userInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                                userInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);
                                userInfo.created_at = reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString();

                                ListUsers.Add(userInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;
        public string email;
        public string phone;
        public string address;
        public string created_at;
    }
}
```

On the update page, I got an error

> **Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '=2' to data type int.
> **
> can anyone help me how to fix it? my code seems to be correct. but I got an error. .................................................

Data Base Structure

[Data Base Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyAfI.jpg)

Comment: Could you please shared your `userInfo model details`? You are trying to pasrse `string` value into `int` or vise-varsa.

Comment: Please share your `UserInfo class` details. In addition, how is your `users` table defination looks like?

Comment: Somewhere you have a typo where you mean to set a parameter to `2` but are accidentally passing in `=2` instead. Find out where that's happening and fix it. We can't see the user input.

Comment: No @KenWhite, the case is here `Request.Form["id"])` it will always consider as `string` unless we convert it into `Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id"])` consequently, the value is compared as '=2' into  `userInfo.id` altogether thus the error encounter, altough, user has inserted value `2`.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: No. What is happening is that the user input is being passed in as `=2`, which the assignment to a numeric parameter is trying to convert to an  integer, which is causing the exception to be raised because `=` can't be converted to an integer. Read the error message, which clearly contains `=2`  - note the **=** sign.

Comment: Yes I also agree with your point, however, `Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id"])` this is also the case. Even this is also invalid `userInfo.id.Length==0` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Could you please shared your `update view page` as well how you are sending request?

Comment: I don't understand why did you unmarked my Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '=2' to data type int. ** can anyone help me how to fix it?

Well, regarding the error you have having with, please double check how you are sending your `query string` it should be like this. `href="/YourController/YourAction?id=@item.id"`

**Output:**

I have tested your code keeping `id` as `string` in the `Model class` that is `Request.Form["id"]` and its working as expected without any error. As you can see the below: So assuming value `=2` has inserted mistakenly.

[image]

However, regarding the `code readibility`, I am not quite sure why you are following this `pattern` to `update and display your list`. You could even do that in easiest way as following keeping the `ADO.NET fashion`

**Another Way To Achieve:**

*Global Variable:*

```
        List<UserInfo> ListUsers = new List<UserInfo>();
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";
```

*Controller: List View:*

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
         
            string connectionString = "Data Source=WX-6899;Initial Catalog=WsAttendance;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM userCaseSO";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                            userInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                            userInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                            userInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                            userInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                            userInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);


                            ListUsers.Add(userInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(ListUsers);
        }
```

*View Should Look Like Below:*

[image]

*Edit Controller Action:*

```
public IActionResult Edit(string Id)
        {
           
            string connectionString = "Data Source=WX-6899;Initial Catalog=WsAttendance;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM userCaseSO WHERE id=@id";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            userInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                            userInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                            userInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                            userInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                            userInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(userInfo);

        }
```

*Edit View:*

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.UserInfo
<div>
    <form asp-action="OnPost" asp-controller="AdoDotNetUserUpdate" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div>
            <h4><strong>Update Info</strong> </h4>

            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="id"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="id" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Enter name" /><span asp-validation-for="id"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="name"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" /><span asp-validation-for="name"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="email"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" /><span asp-validation-for="email"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="phone"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone" /><span asp-validation-for="phone"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="address"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address" /><span asp-validation-for="address"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:107px">Update</button></th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "Index", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

*Edit View Page Should Look Like Below:*

[image]

*Edit Submit Controller:*

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            userInfo.id = Request.Form["id"];
            userInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
            userInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            userInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            userInfo.address = Request.Form["address"];

            if (userInfo.id.Length == 0 || userInfo.name.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the field are required";
               
            }

            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=WX-6899;Initial Catalog=WsAttendance;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "UPDATE userCaseSO " +
                               "SET name=@name, email=@email, phone=@phone, address=@address " +
                               "WHERE id=@id";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", userInfo.name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", userInfo.email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", userInfo.phone);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", userInfo.address);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userInfo.id);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
             
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Final Output:**

[image]

**Note:** There are even elegant way to implement that considering your understanding, this can be improved at this level for now.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you tried to convert column DataType from String to int which is not right. You may try to cast the `ID` as Integer like

```
 CAST(@ID AS int)
```

or

```
CONVERT(int,@ID)
```